# How can I get my filters to work on Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to filter through forms with this code that used to work in access 2000 and now doesn't work. I've inherited a really old database and am in the process of rebuilding it bit by bit but I'm trying to get the old one to continue working while I finish this one.
This is the VBA Code

```
Public Function SpecialLoadAndPopulateTheFilterForm(strBaseTable As String)
Dim strFilterFormName As String
Dim frm As Form
strFilterFormName = "frm" & strBaseTable & "Filter"
DoCmd.OpenForm strFilterFormName
Set frm = Forms(strFilterFormName)
frm!optnOpen = CBool(Nz(INIGetSettingString(strBaseTable & " Filter", "Open", gcnstStrSRCiniPath, "True"), "True"))
frm!optnClose = CBool(Nz(INIGetSettingString(strBaseTable & " Filter", "Close", gcnstStrSRCiniPath, "True"), "True"))
frm!optnHold = CBool(Nz(INIGetSettingString(strBaseTable & " Filter", "Hold", gcnstStrSRCiniPath, "False"), "False"))
If strBaseTable = "Employees" Then
    Dim bolValue As Boolean
    Dim ctlList As Control
    Dim intRow As Integer
    Set ctlList = frm!lstEmpTypeFilter
    For intRow = 0 To ctlList.ListCount - 1
        bolValue = CBool(Nz(INIGetSettingString(strBaseTable & " Types Filter", Trim(CStr(ctlList.Column(1, intRow))), _
            gcnstStrSRCiniPath, "False"), "False"))
        ctlList.Selected(intRow) = bolValue
    Next intRow
End If
End Function
```

Comment: @Parfait I fixed the code up top, I realize there's a reference to an INIGetSettingString that's defined later, but I'm thinking there's no command in the database that calls up or writes that INI file.

Comment: @Parfait Basically what's supposed to happen is we have a database of clients and the filter is supposed to filter out open and closed and on hold clients from the forms. The code works on WIndows XP machines but doesn't work on Windows 7 forward.